# Ren'py / Python - insert dynamic variable in class with a while loop - without overwriting with append

Tags: python, renpy

I'm currently trying to get into Python and Ren'Py a bit. Since I like to design a lot dynamically
and don't want to use copy&paste so often, I'm trying to create a page that will have `ImageButtons` with the corresponding number I specify.

In the example below I use "4" - but this can be higher.

I have built a class for this purpose:

```
Example:
    init python:
        class PictureSettings(object):
            def __init__ (self, ImgIdle, ImgHover, LabelCall):
                self.ImgIdle = ImgIdle
                self.ImgHover = ImgHover
                self.LabelCall = LabelCall
                return
```

For the Idle/Hover and for the Jump.

If I insert in the code now in an object each entry "manually" with append I get all 4 pictures as desired indicated.

```
Example: (Works - but is not dynamic)
    python:
        var_pictures = []
        var_pictures.append(PictureSettings("img_picture_1_idle", "img_picture_1_hover", "picture_1"))
        var_pictures.append(PictureSettings("img_picture_2_idle", "img_picture_2_hover", "picture_2"))
        var_pictures.append(PictureSettings("img_picture_3_idle", "img_picture_3_hover", "picture_3"))
        var_pictures.append(PictureSettings("img_picture_4_idle", "img_picture_4_hover", "picture_4"))
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
Example (Here I get only ""img_picture_4_idle", "img_picture_4_hover", "picture_4""):
    $ countlimit = 4
    $ count = 1
        
    python:
        while count < countlimit:
        var_pictures = []
        var_pictures.append(PictureSettings(
            ImgIdle = "img_picture_[count]_idle",
            ImgHover = "img_picture_[count]_hover",
            LabelCall = "picture_[count]"))
        count += 1
```

Have already tried various things, unfortunately without success.
For example: with Add - instead of append (because this overwrites the result and leaves only the last entry
I get the following error:

```
var_pictures.add(PictureSettings( AttributeError: 'RevertableList' object has no attribute 'add')
```

Maybe someone can help me with the solution so I can keep my code dynamic without copying something X times.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your list inside your loop, so it is recreated every time.
At the end, you only get the last created list.

```py
var_pictures = []
while count < countlimit:
    var_pictures.append(PictureSettings(
        ImgIdle = "img_picture_[count]_idle",
        ImgHover = "img_picture_[count]_hover",
        LabelCall = "picture_[count]"))
    count += 1
```

On another subject, if you want to do this in a more pythonic  way:

```py
pictures = []  # no need for var_, we know its a variable
for i in range(1, 5):
    pictures.append(PictureSettings(
        # in python, we prefere snake_case attributes
        img_idle=f'img_picture_{i}_idle',
        img_hover=f'img_picture_{i}_hover',
        ...
    ))

# or even shorter with list comprehension
pictures = [
    PictureSettings(
        img_idle=f'img_picture_{i}_idle',
    )
    for i in range(1, 5)
]
```

By the way, no need to `return` in your class constructor